# Can I flash a Clonezilla image to an external disk and boot from it?

Tags: clonezilla

I have a Clonezilla image of an Ubuntu 14.04 ext4 partition. If I restore that image to an external disk, will I automatically be able to boot from that drive?

After booting, can I then install programs, save and edit files, and thus have a portable Ubuntu system that I can work with over multiple computers?

Comment: No. You can only convert it to an iso and literally burn it or use something like Pendrive Linux's UUI if you want to use a USB.

Comment: How can I convert the Clonezilla image to ISO? Couldn't find instructions by Googling.

Comment: http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=alternative And file type = ISO

Comment: I meant the Clonezilla image of the ext4 Ubuntu partition, how can I convert it to ISO? Since that is what I need to do to create a bootable, customizable Ubuntu external drive.